# Android heads up notifications not work In huawei

Tags: android, android-studio, android-8.0-oreo, huawei-developers

**In Huawei equipment, how to apply for banner notification permission, he is turned off by default**
**I made the following Settings, which only worked when I manually turned on the banner notifications**
**How to solve ?**

```java
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    String channelId = "007";
                    String channelName = "James Bond";
                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
                    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplication(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
                    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this, "007")
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setContentTitle("What is 5G ?")
                            .setContentText("But before we get to the smart phones, let's simply figure out what 5G is.")
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setVibrate(new long[0])
                            //.setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent, true)
                            .build();
                    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
                }
```

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
```